# Проблема с переходом по второй ссылке

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Я пытаюсь автоматизировать действия браузера и столкнулся с проблемой, которую сам решить не смог. Прочитал много всего в интернете, в официальной документации, но не справился. Я в этом деле новичок и хотел бы понять что именно я делаю не так. Ниже я опишу проблему и предоставлю код, который не работает. Проблема появляется на предпоследнем шаге (см. коммент ниже). Это еще не реальный проект, я пока что учусь. Я пытался осуществить такую задумку:

1. Открываем поисковик.
2. Даём необходимый нам запрос (находим кнопку поиска и жмём на неё)
3. Открывается список сайтов, удовлетворяющих нашим ожиданиям.
4. Среди предоставленных поисковиком сайтов выбираем первый и кликаем на него.
5. На этом шаге мы уже оказываемся на новом сайте и там необходимо также выбрать какую-то ссылку и перейти по ней. Вот тут и выскакивает проблема.

Ниже я привел пример с xpath, но я пробовал разными методами. Например тем же самым что и предыдущий до него шаг (пытался найти ссылку с помощью частичного указания текста). В предыдущем шаге все нормально и код работает и переходит по ссылке. Но вот уже оказавшись на другом сайте (не в поисковике), тот же самый метод не работает. Выдаёт ошибку, которая указана в самом низу после кода.
Дополню, что если я использую тот путь где выдаёт ошибку как первый степ, тоесть без поисковика, то он работает. Это означает что путь к ссылке верный, но именно когда код начинается с другого сайта и по ходу переходит на этот, возникает ошибка при переходе по 3-й ссылке.

```
import time 

link = "url поисковика"

try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(link)

    input1 = browser.find_element_by_class_name("необходимый путь")
    input1.send_keys("необходимый input")
    button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("необходимый путь по css")
    button.click()
    link2 = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("часть текста в ссылке")
    link2.click()
    link2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("необходимый путь по xpath") #Проблема появляется на этом шаге, если я использую этот степ как первый (без поисковика, то всё получается.Это означает что путь к ссылке правильный, но почему-то он не работает когда весь код начинается с другого сайта. 
    link2.click()

finally:
    time.sleep(30)
    browser.quit()
    
    Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, так в чем же проблема? Не можете выбрать второй результат в выдаче поисковика? Тогда вам не xpath нужен, а выбор набора элементов по css-селекторам. Метод называется `find_elements_by_css_selector`. Ему нужно передать селектор.  Метод вернет коллекцию элементов со ссылками. Вот их в цикле и надо протыкивать

Comment: Нет, не совсем так. Может быть я плохо объяснил проблему. В поисковике все ок, тоесть я нахожу первую ссылку и перехожу по ней и оказываюсь на другом сайте (уже не в поисковике) и там мне нужно снова найти первую ссылку, также как я это делал ранее в поисковике. Вот тут уже не получается кликнуть по первой ссылке. Я пробовал разные методы и css selector в том числе

Comment: Вы пытаетесь по алгоритму работы с одним сайтом, работать на другом? Естественно оно не будет работать. Структуры сайтов все разные. Отличаются и селекторы, и xpath, и код страниц. в 99,9% случаев код поиска ссылки от одного сайта не подойдет к другому сайту

Comment: Я использую один и тот же метод, но естественно не копирую путь к элементу. Я имел ввиду что использую тот же способ (метод). Путь к элементу я нахожу на втором сайте и вписываю его как положено, но код не работает. Я хочу понять может что то нужно дополнительно сделать между переходм с одного сайта на другой. Я не копирую один и тот же селектор, а ищу новый на втором сайте.

Comment: Когда я использую этот же путь (тот что выдаёт ошибку) как первый степ, тоесть без поисковика, то никаких проблем нет и ссылка открывается. Проблема возникает именно тогда, когда мой код начинается с другого сайта и переходит на следующий.

Comment: Блин, ну вот как тебе объяснить, что недостаточно просто менять селекторы? Структура страниц везде разная. Даже на одном и том же домене, визуально одинаковые страницы могут достаточно сильно отличаться друг от друга по структуре и требовать совершенно разного python-кода для работы с ними. Жми в браузере F12 и изучай html-код страниц. Больше ничего без конкретики сказать нельзя.